# How does one check if a javascript variable is referenced, and from where?

Tags: javascript

JS does not have public/private variables, but everything is accessible from pretty much anywhere.

Is it possible to check what other variables reference another variable?

```
var firstVar = "Hello";
someObject.secondVar = firstVar;
checkReferences(someObject.secondVar);

=> firstVar
```

Or something along these lines.

Comment: You can't access variables from everywhere. It depends on the scope of the variable.

Comment: No, but you are freer than in many other languages. Not everywhere, but pretty much.

Answer (score 2):

`someObject.secondVar` would have the same value as `firstVar`, but it doesn't *reference* it. If you change the value of one, it won't change the value of the other.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for asking a question I was close to finding out the answer to.

I should have asked whether or not JS passes by reference or value. It's by value, until you pass Objects {}. So the question does not really make sense.

[This answer is good reading for anyone who was wondering the same as me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5314911/1364334)